# Unix sockets with getaddrinfo() in C

Tags: c, sockets, getaddrinfo

Does anyone know if it's possible to use getaddrinfo with unix sockets in C (AF_UNIX). I've tried a couple of things but I can't make it work.
This is basically what I'm trying:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family   = AF_UNIX;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
if(getaddrinfo("What should I put here?", "What should I put here?", &hints, &res) != 0){
    //do sth about
}
```

My question is how to fill the node and service fields, in case that is possible to use it with unix sockets.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? How do you call 'getaddrinfo'?

Answer (score 5):

Some implementations of `getaddrinfo()` have supported `AF_UNIX` socket addresses, but they no longer do so due to security concerns.

You don't really need a function to "look up" an `AF_UNIX` address anyway - if you know the socket path, then you can just copy it straight into a `sockaddr_un` of sufficient size.  There's no resolution step for `AF_UNIX` addresses - the socket name *is* the socket address.

Answer (score -1):

From [`man 3 getaddrinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo):

> The *hints* parameter specifies the preferred socket type, or protocol. A NULL hints specifies that any network address or protocol is acceptable. If this parameter is not NULL it points to an addrinfo structure whose ai_family, ai_socktype, and ai_protocol members specify the preferred socket type. AF_UNSPEC in ai_family specifies any protocol family (either IPv4 or IPv6, for example). 0 in ai_socktype or ai_protocol specifies that any socket type or protocol is acceptable as well. The ai_flags member specifies additional options, defined below. Multiple flags are specified by logically OR-ing them together. All the other members in the hints parameter must contain either 0, or a null pointer.

So it looks like you need to pass in the `hints` parameter to tell it you want a unix socket.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I don't know where I have to set the file which points to the socket. I've tried to do it in the first and second arg of getaddrinfo and it doesn't work.

Comment: @esteban Isn't that a pretty good hint that `getaddrinfo` isn't valid for Unix sockets?  You neither have a valid `node` or `service` to provide the API.

Comment: @Steve-o as you said, those are just hints. I'm looking for a definitive answer, otherwise I wouldn't have made the question at all. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @esteban look at `man getnameinfo` which is more likely to be Unix socket friendly and the Linux page lists only `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6` support.

Answer (score -1):

A lot late, but just for the records, did you try this - 
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;   //is the address family(IPV4 or 6) or UNSPEC for either
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 
if(getaddrinfo(parm1, parm2, &hints, &res) != 0){
    //do sth about
}
```

parm1 -> is the host name or address to connect to. A call with NULL here puts the address of local host, in which case you specify hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE. 
parm2 -> is the name of the intended service (http, ftp etc) or the corresponding port number for that service the socket is used for

Comment: Answer has nothing to do with unix domain sockets.